# Service notification open main activity

Tags: android, service

Ok,
I am working on an Android app that uses a service to collect & process GPS data.  The service also creates a notification in the status bar.  What I cannot figure out is how to have the notification open the main class when a user clicks on it.  From what I've found online it shouldn't be that hard to do, but I cannot get it to work.  Does anyone have some suggestions on where to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
```

This line of code is from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html.

Simply replace MyClass with your activity class - it will be launched when you click the notification.

Comment: Now I feel stupid.  I already had the code in my service for it, but had one mistake :(  I had GPSService.class instead of Main.class.  The exact code I used is PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, Main.class), 0);